# Convert RSS pubDate Date to MM-DD-YY HH:MM

Tags: ruby, date, rss

I have a string, the value of this string is an rss date. I want to convert the value of this string / the rss date into another format (MM-DD-YY HH:MM). Any ideas how to do this?

This is an extract of what I got so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rss/2.0'
require 'rss/content'

[...]

date = rss.items[i].pubDate
date = #Here I want to convert the date
puts date

[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date.parse` to get a `Date` object from a string and then `Date#strftime` to format it correctly.

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime

Here's a `strftime` example:

```
Time.now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M") #=> "03-27-2012 12:03
```